# How to calculate the vertices of a rectangle, where the smallest side is perpendicular to a known line?

Tags: geometry

I have two points (for context they are geographical coordinates: latitude, longitude, but it doesn't matter really) and I want to build two rectangles such that the mid-point of the smallest side of the rectangle is one of the points of the line, the side is perpendicular to the line and the rectangles do not include the line.

[image]

I know the coordinates of $A$ and $B$, and the size of each side of the rectangle (let's call them $s$ for the smallest side and $l$ for the largest). I would like to know the four vertices of each rectangle.

Comment: Do you assume 2D plane?

Comment: Yes, cartesian coordinates.

Comment: You know the line through AB and than the s are perpendicular and l parallel to this line